# How do I unlock the Modify Genetic Codes without buying them?

Tags: plague-inc

In Plague Inc there are 25 genes to discover (5 per spot) that you can use prior to launching the game that gives you a boost / alters the gameplay.

It says:

> "You can discover all of these genes - just by playing the game".

What in game combinations or actions trigger these Gene unlocks?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What in game combinations or actions trigger these Gene unlocks?

**Beating the game**

Any time your virus/bacteria/etc. succeeds in wiping out humanity, you will get a *random* gene unlocked. So far as I've been able to tell, there is no way to influence which genes get unlocked; you just have to keep playing until you randomly receive the one(s) you most want.

Also, as @Studoku pointed out in the comments, you must have already purchased the game to use any genes; they simply will not unlock in the unpaid trial. And to further clarify that, you have to buy the game itself, and then you have the opportunity to unlock genes by either spending more money, or playing the game -- there's "freemium", and then there's this, where you have to pay to have the privilege of paying for more!

Comment: I beat the game quite a few times, but any time I want to use use/equip them, it says I have to buy the game. Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't get to pick which ones you get, the game chooses random ones for you. You'll see that message when you try to use ones you haven't yet unlocked.

Comment: @Nolonar You have to buy the full game to be able to use them, which costs $1.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Studoku, I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

With the latest upgrade I've finally been able to insert genes by simply watching 30 second game ads...just try your unlocked genes and continue unlocking new ones.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, especially with the special disease types, you just have to win. To unlock the gene modifiers in the special diseases, you have to win with that type. I do not know if difficulty influences which ones you unlock, and I'm not sure if beating them on any difficulty will unlock a gene each time. I've beaten all but the zombie and simian flu diseases on brutal. I've unlocked two simian flu specials but none of the necrosis virus modifiers.